# Prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n(n+2)}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Prove that the series 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n(n+2)}$ is convergent

I know the series is convergent if the sequence of partial sums is convergent.

$\begin{align*}
s_n&=a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_n\\
&=\frac{2}{1\cdot 3}+\frac{2}{2\cdot 4}+\frac{2}{3\cdot 5}+\cdots+\frac{2}{n(n+2)}\\
&<\frac{1}{2 \cdot 1}+\frac{1}{2 \cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3 \cdot 4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\\
&=(1- \frac{1}{2})+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4})+\cdots+(\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n})\\
&=1-\frac{1}{n}\\
&<1
\end{align*}$

Thus we see that $1$ is an upper bound for the sequence of partial sums, and clearly the sequence is increasing since $0\leq a_n\leq a_{n+1}$. Therefore by the monotone convergence theorem we know that the series 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n(n+2)}$ is convergent.

Comment: Hint - try partial sums.

Comment: Can't see why you have your first inequality. Looks like it should be the opposite...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: 
$$\dfrac{2}{n(n+2)} = \dfrac{2}{n^2 +2n} \leq \dfrac{2}{n^2}$$
for all $n \geq 1$, 
and 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2}{n^2}$$
is proportional to a convergent $p$-series. These are both non-negative series. Now apply Limit Comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where your first inequality comes from. You can solve your problem as follows:\begin{align}\frac2{1.3}+\frac2{2.4}+\frac2{3.5}+\cdots&<\frac2{1.2}+\frac2{2.3}+\frac2{3.4}+\cdots\\&=2\left(1-\frac12+\frac12-\frac13+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots\right)\\&<2.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\frac2{n(n+2)}=\frac1n-\frac1{n+2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another hint:
$$\frac{2}{n(n+2)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2},$$
So that the sum telescopes.

Specifically $(1-1/3)+(1/2-1/4)+(1/3-1/5) \cdots =3/2.$